# How to vertically center anchor tag text inside of a ul li

Tags: css, html-lists, anchor, vertical-alignment

Here is my html:

```
<ul id="sub_nav" class="block_hide trim no_list no_line" style="display: block; left: 524.5px;">
<li><a href="/path1" class="one">1st button</a></li>
<li><a href="/path2" class="one">2nd button</a></li>
<li><a href="/path3" class="one">3rd button</a></li>
</ul>
```

I also attached an image if what I currently have. I tried adding display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;  to the anchor tag class but it did not work I also tried adding a span around teh anchor tag with a class with: display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; but that did not work either, in both cases button's heights were not constant.

How can I vertically center text and keep my buttons height and width the same?

[image]

Ended up going with the display:table-cell solution as it was the most cross browser....I did not like it at first because I had to hard code the width of my button instead of 100% but once I got past that it was a solid solution:
    my li:

```
.header #sub_nav li {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    width: 86%;
}
```

my a:

```
    .header #sub_nav li a {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 45px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 111px;
}
```

Comment: please, show the css code or provide URL

Comment: Your code does not match your image - it is useless. It would help if you could set up a realistic jsfiddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Do something similar to what you're asking. Defining the parent as "display: table" and the element itself with "vertical-align:middle" & "display:table-cell" worked for me.

Comment: It changes the height of my buttons

Answer (score 5):

If you have only one item within the li (or div, etc), the easiest way is to set line-height to be the same as the element's height, and it will be vertically aligned. I have created a simple fiddle below, and hope this helps!
http://jsfiddle.net/fCkLJ/

```
li {
  /* other styling */
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
li{
padding-top:20%;
padding-bottom:20%;
}
```

This will cause even padding top/bottom on the LI but if one LI wraps and another one doesnt it they will be different heights.

http://jsfiddle.net/VMCH6/1/

Comment: Thanks, but it causes the buttons to be different heights which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, [looks here](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/priklady/vertical-align-valid-solution-en.html)

Comment: this solution uses the table method that I had mentioned did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `background-image`, then you should set a fixed width height for the `li.a` element and use this hack for the a element:

```
li a {
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto 0;
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    box-align: center;
}
```

This is the working example (even with your image as background). The complete button will be clickable and the flexibility to be multiple lines:

http://jsfiddle.net/GqBAL/494/

**Note:** This is not 100% cross-browser, but is the best solution.

Comment: Will this vertically align only? Because I don't want horizontal align. Which IE browsers will it work in?

Comment: Check the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/GqBAL/494/) with different browsers and IE to check. What do you mean with "I don't want horizontal align"?

Comment: I meant I don't want horizontal centering.

Comment: You can control that using `margin`/`padding`, this example is not horizontal centering

Comment: This def works in Chrome (webkit based browsers), but have not tested on other browsers yet...thanks Tom!

Comment: Ok did not work on firefox, it makes the button's width extend all the way to its parent's width not respecting the margin-right.

Comment: Turns out Could not use your solution, couldn't get to work in Firefox...thx anyways..

Answer (score -1):

I dont have enough knowledge of HTML/CSS but i think it is Ok .

in this answer i have removed height from `UL/LI` and provided auto height , and in anchor `<a>` tag i have used padding , to display a `bigger-height-centralized` button .

CSS part is :

```
<style>
html , body , ul , li 
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html , body
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
ul
{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;    
    background-color:red;
}
li
{
    width:33%;
    height:auto;    
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green; 
}
a
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    padding-top:10%;
    padding-bottom:10%;
}
</style>
```

HTML part is :

```
<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="">tushar</a></li>
<li><a href="">tushar</a></li>
<li><a href="">tushar</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```