# force text onto two lines within li

Tags: html, css

I have a html dcument that I am trying to style, it contains a pair of unordered lists of links (and a span), the second of which I want to have circular backgrounds for the links which I have acheived, however I need to make the text of the links break over multiple lines (one word per line probably)

the markup is:

```
<div class="controls">
    <ul class="betrow">
        <li><a href="#" class="btn secondary">pop up 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn decrease">add more</a></li>
        <li><span>1</span></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn increase">take away</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn secondary">pop up 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- PLAY ROW -->
    <ul class="playrow">
        <li><a href="#" class="btn">Quick Play</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn">Play 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn primary">Play</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn">Play 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn oneline">Clear</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the styling I have applied to this is:

```
    html {
        font-size: 62.5%;
    }
    body {
        font-family: 'Allan', Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1rem;
        letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
        min-width: 320px;
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
    }
    .controls {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    z-index: 1; 
    border: 10px solid #630;
    }
    .controls ul {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 70%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    }
    .controls ul li {
    float: left;
    }
    .controls ul.betrow {
    margin: 2px auto 10px;

}

.controls ul.playrow {
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
}

.controls ul.playrow li,
.controls ul.betrow li {
    display: block;
    width: 18.4%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    height: 30px;
}



.controls ul.betrow li a,
.controls ul.betrow li span{
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.controls ul.playrow li a,
.controls ul.playrow li span{
    border-radius: 25px;
    max-width: 30px;
    min-width:30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:center;
    word-spacing:0px;
    font-size:0.8rem;
    word-break:break-all;
    word-wrap:break-word;   
}

.controls ul.betrow li:last-child,
.controls ul.playrow li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.controls ul li a,
.controls ul li span {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;    
}

.controls ul li span {
    overflow: visible;
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: #111;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    animation: scalePulse 5s ease-in-out infinite;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #FFF;
}

.controls ul li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #1c1e00; 
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #030;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #FFF;
    border: 4px solid #630; 
}

.controls ul li a:hover,
.controls ul li a:active,
.controls ul li a:focus {
    background-color: #1c0e00;
    border: 5px solid #630; 
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
}

.controls ul li a.primary {
    font-size: 1.8rem;  
    background-size:90%;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    padding-top:10px;   
    height: 40px; 
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    max-width:none;
}

.controls ul li a.primary:hover,
.controls ul li a.primary:active,
.controls ul li a.primary:focus {
    background-image: url('../images/game2/bg_plank.svg');  
}

.controls ul li a.secondary {
    background-color: #1c0e00;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #00275B;
    display: none;
}

.controls ul li a.secondary:hover,
.controls ul li a.secondary:active,
.controls ul li a.secondary:focus {
    background-color: #1c0e00;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out 0s;
}

.controls ul li a.increase,
.controls ul li a.decrease {
    background-color: #1c0e00; 
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #300;
}

.controls ul li a.increase:hover,
.controls ul li a.decrease:hover,
.controls ul li a.increase:active,
.controls ul li a.decrease:active,
.controls ul li a.increase:focus,
.controls ul li a.decrease:focus {
    background-color: #1C0E00;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

I have tried adding word-break:break-all; and word-wrap:break-word; but neither has helped.

To clarify I only want the text 'Quick Play', 'Play 5', 'Play 10' to split over 2 lines so that they fit nicely in the circular background of their anchor.

Comment: can you put this in a http://jsfiddle.net where we can see the problem?

Comment: did you try <br> in between words ? ?

If you just want to add a line break I think <br> will do your job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have white-space:nowrap in there which tells the browser not to do this wrapping that the browser would otherwise do automatically.

The other issue is you have used line-height to vertically centre your button text, which unfortunately will cause your text to wrap too far down and make your buttons look worse!

Comment: ou are quite right about the line height, I have removed the white-space style, and also set line-height:1;  now I need to centre the text somehow.

Comment: vertically center the text that is

Comment: found this post useful to solve the vertical alignment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963564/how-to-vertically-center-anchor-tag-text-inside-of-a-ul-li

Comment: @MikeW indeed, you're using links for a start, I think buttons do this automatically: http://jsfiddle.net/NN2TK/

Answer (score 0):

How about using br tag then ?

```
<li><a href="#" class="btn">Quick <br />Play</a></li>
```

Comment: then you also have to adjust your line-height. its arround 2em and your circle displays as circle.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to your css:

```
.playrow li{width: 25px;}
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XG8j8/)

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/SyKnv/15/)

Instead of using `<br />` and `fixed width` you can use one more trick.

Which is `word-spacing`.

```
.playrow li a { word-spacing:999em; }
```

Also, there is no chance of any side-effects of using `word-spacing`